# How to clear Heroku releases?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have deployed in my Rails application in Heroku.

And on Heroku

```
$ heroku releases

=== my_app Releases

v34  Deploy b18bae5                    user@example.com  2014/06/23 13:21:52 
v33  Deploy 433982b                    user@example.com  2014/06/23 12:24:31 
v32  Deploy 028406a                    user@example.com  2014/06/23 09:53:50 
v31  Rollback to v29                   user@example.com  2014/06/23 17:45:47
v30  Deploy ffead56                    user@example.com  2014/06/22 17:04:51 
v29  Deploy gghjk21                    user@example.com  2014/05/24 12:19:43
v28  Deploy b18bae5                    user@example.com  2014/05/20 14:52:19
v27  Deploy 8b72be3                    user@example.com  2014/05/20 13:56:48
```

I want to remove particular release only, example I want to remove v29. How to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without destroying the app and recreating.

Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your answer...The reason is I have added some extra features in version 30(v30). So If someone did rollback to v30, then everybody can see..I dont want to see others. And also i have deleted v30 code from heroku git repository using git reset command. So Git log also cleared. But in heroku I couldn't clear...

Comment: Ok, well I think you're out of luck. If you could delete releases, it would kind of defeat the object.

Answer (score -1):

try `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo` then `heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname`

If the did not work go to the url [How do I clear the build cache?](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache)

Comment: This clears the build cache, but the question was about releases.